# Reference nameref to a label in a subsection command is not working

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

I want to create a command for *subsections* which should be referenced and indexable.
The command has two params: code and name.

The command creates the subsection and the ***name*** (second parameter) is painted in the toc.

But when I try to use the ***code*** as a reference, it writes the name of a different (the first one) subsection!!

[image]

This is my **not** working code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue,
}
\newcommand{\virtualSubsec}[3]{
    \phantomsection
    \par\nopagebreak
    \refstepcounter{subsection}
    \def\@currentlabelname{#1}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}#2}
    \label{#1}
    \textbf{#1 - #2}
    \par
    \textit{#3} 
    \par
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{This is a Section}
\subsection{This is a Subsection}

A line of text... 
\virtualSubsec{VS01}{Virtual Subsec 1}{
    this is the content of the first virtual subsection
}
\virtualSubsec{VS02}{Virtual Subsec 2}{
    this is the content of the second virtual subsection
}

\section{References}
autoref VS02 is working: \par
\autoref{VS02} \par %true => is subsection 1.2 
nameref VS02 is NOT working: \par
\nameref{VS02} \par 
it is painting "This is a Subsection" => false => it should be "Virtual Subsec 1"

\end{document}
```

what is the problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must make @ a letter first. Without it you are defining `\@` and not `\@currentlabelname`. Also you are using the wrong argument number:

```
\makeatletter %<-- make @ a letter
\newcommand{\virtualSubsec}[3]{
    \phantomsection
    \par\nopagebreak
    \refstepcounter{subsection}
    \def\@currentlabelname{#2}%<------ #2
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}#2}
    \label{#1}
    \textbf{#1 - #2}
    \par
    \textit{#3}
    \par
}
\makeatother
```